# How to launch a rails 3 app on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

How do I launch a Rails 3 app on Heroku.
I am using PHPmyadmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start [here](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart)

Comment: How do I sync Heroku with my table in MySql?

Comment: You can push your local database to Heroku using taps. It's fully documented here: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/taps

Comment: Is it possiable to use PHPmyadmin?

Answer (score 1):

yep, you need to read the manual. Heroku is entirely managed system, you can only deploy via a git push. By default it uses Postgresql as it's DB - you can use mySQL but you'd have to pay for an Amazon mySQL server

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should read through the [Ruby on Rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book). It guides you through the process of developing an app in RoR and pushing it to Heroku. Good luck.

This part, especially, has information on deployment to heroku:

[Heroku Deployment](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec:1.4.1)